# Remove groups by condition

Tags: dataframe, julia

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = ["a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d"])
grouped_df  = groupby(df, "B")
```

I would have four groups. How can I drop the groups that have fewer than, say, 2 rows? For example, how can I keep only groups `a`,`b`, and `c`? I can easily do it with a for loop, but I don't think the optimal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the result to be still grouped then `filter` is simplest:

```
julia> filter(x -> nrow(x) > 1, grouped_df)
GroupedDataFrame with 3 groups based on key: B
First Group (2 rows): B = "a"
 Row │ A      B
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  a
⋮
Last Group (4 rows): B = "c"
 Row │ A      B
     │ Int64  String
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     6  c
   2 │     7  c
   3 │     8  c
   4 │     9  c
```

If you want to get a data frame as a result of one operation then do e.g.:

```
julia> combine(grouped_df, x -> nrow(x) < 2 ? DataFrame() : x)
9×2 DataFrame
 Row │ B       A
     │ String  Int64
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a           2
   3 │ b           3
   4 │ b           4
   5 │ b           5
   6 │ c           6
   7 │ c           7
   8 │ c           8
   9 │ c           9
```

Comment: I wanted to keep it as grouped, but when I ran your first command, I get `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching filter(::var"#15#16", ::GroupedDataFrame{DataFrame})`

Comment: Please make sure that you are using the latest version of DataFrames.jl, which is 0.22.5 at the moment of writing. This post describes ways to check it: https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2021/02/27/pkg_version.html and in this post https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/11/package-version-restrictions.html you have information how to check what potentially blocks DataFrames.jl to be installed in its latest version in your project environment.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński: This works as expected, thanks! However, is it possible to do this operation "in-place"? I think this makes another copy of the original dataframe df in the memory. Am I right?

Comment: The operation with `filter` does not make a copy. It just only keeps the groups that you want. The underlying data frame remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to use [subset](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.subset):

```
subset(grouped_df, :B => x -> length(x) >= 2)
```

If you want to keep the groups, then simply set `ungroup = false`. You can also avoid the copying performed by `combine` by setting `view = true` or do the operation in-place with [subset!](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.subset!).